# Opening localhost ports using python script

Tags: python, localhost, ports

Is there anyway I can open a port on my local machine via a python script? I have looked into the socket package and found only `socket.connect()` and `socket.close()`. Is there any built in method or an external package which has something like `socket.open()` method?

Comment: you can use https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.listen to listen for incoming connections. Here is an example: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example

Answer (score 2):

You should use `socket.bind` and `socket.listen`, for example:

```
host = ''                                                                                                                               
port = int(input('Enter the port: '))                                           
socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)  

socket.bind((host, port))                                                    
socket.listen(1)
```